How to make the player stop moving when doing a specific animation, like sitting?
I am using New Input System, Starter Asset - Third Person Controller
I wanted to include new input and animations (from Mixamo).
Which I successfully put. However, there is a problem: when I press Z to Sit then moving WASD, the player can move while sitting.
I want player do not move (or disable movement) when doing the animation Sit.
StarterAssetsInputs.cs
[Header("Character Input Values")]
        public Vector2 move;
        public Vector2 look;
        public bool jump;
        public bool sprint;
        
        public bool sit; //my input

        [Header("Movement Settings")]
        public bool analogMovement;

        [Header("Mouse Cursor Settings")]
        public bool cursorLocked = true;
        public bool cursorInputForLook = true;

        public bool disableMovement = false; //my input

public void OnSit(InputValue value)
        {
            SitInput(value.isPressed);
        }

public void SitInput(bool newSitInput)
        {
            if (newSitInput)
            {
                sit = !sit;
                disableMovement = sit;
            }
        }

ThirdPersonControllers.cs
// animation IDs
        private int _animIDSpeed;
        private int _animIDGrounded;
        private int _animIDJump;
        private int _animIDFreeFall;
        private int _animIDMotionSpeed;
        
        private int _animIDSit; //my input

ENABLE_INPUT_SYSTEM 
        private PlayerInput _playerInput;
#endif
        private Animator _animator;
        private CharacterController _controller;
        private StarterAssetsInputs _input;
        private GameObject _mainCamera;

        private const float _threshold = 0.01f;

        private bool _hasAnimator;

private void Update()
        {
            _hasAnimator = TryGetComponent(out _animator);
    
            JumpAndGravity();
            GroundedCheck();
            Move();
            Sit();
        }

 private void AssignAnimationIDs()
        {
            _animIDSpeed = Animator.StringToHash("Speed");
            _animIDGrounded = Animator.StringToHash("Grounded");
            _animIDJump = Animator.StringToHash("Jump");
            _animIDFreeFall = Animator.StringToHash("FreeFall");
            _animIDMotionSpeed = Animator.StringToHash("MotionSpeed");
            _animIDSit = Animator.StringToHash("Sitting");//my input
        }

 void Sit()
        {
            if (_hasAnimator)
            {
                _animator.SetBool(_animIDSit, _input.sit);

            }
        }


What did I try : I did put the code directly to StarterAssetsInputs.cs and ThirdPersonControllers.cs that already available from Unity Store. I just put my code according to some YT and forum.

What were I expecting is... I want player do not move (or disable movement) when doing the animation Sit.


Thank you.

Can't you just have a bool canMovement = true; that you set to false when you want to disable movement and in your Update() you add an if (canMove) above your Move()-call?

in an overall sense, you have to know state of your character to do decisions. make an enum and add states to it. then, if you are sitting, ignore input from your movement routine.

Hi MaxPlay, Thank you for the response, appreciated it!

Hi, nobodyMore, yes  I need learn the state. Im making this for prototype. but thank you for the response, appreciate it!

In Update where you are handling the movement, you can stop it from there by doing a simple check:
private void Update()
{
    _hasAnimator = TryGetComponent(out _animator);

    if (!_input.disableMovement) // Check if movement is disabled
    {
        JumpAndGravity();
        GroundedCheck();
        Move();
    }
    Sit();
}

Since you are disabling the movement, it shouldn't allow you to move, and you can also do a simple return like:
private void Move()
{
    if (_input.disableMovement) return;
}

But also make sure the animator is updated in ThirdPersonController.

Hi, It's worked! Thank you very much for your response! Appreciated it!

I'm glad it worked!
